# Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/svn.so'

Tags: php, svn, ubuntu, pagespeed

Following installation of [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_mod_pagespeed_from_source) prerequisites, running this command on Ubuntu 11.10

> php -V

receives the following error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/svn.so' - libsvn_client-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

I commented out the following line from /etc/php5/conf.d/svn.ini, which of course stopped the error. However I would still like to know what I need to do to resolve this error in order to include the extension?

> extension=svn.so

Thanks! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-svn
```